# .htaccess: Strange url have slash / at the end of urls, and .php

Tags: .htaccess

I have check google webmaster tools and see lot of URLs that has been crawled, they look like:

```
mydomain.com/somefile.php/index.php 
or 
mydomain.com/somefile.php/somefilesss.php?aaa=bbb&ddd=ddd
or
mydomain.com/somefile.php/someffiiii.php?iii=uuu/somefilesss.php?aaa=bbb&ddd=ddd
```

This is really strange.
Look like someone add the slash to URL when enter address bar, then google following them.
Currently I get fix by remove slash at the end of URLs by this .htaccess:

If it come like `.php/`, it will become `.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]
```

But the issue is other URL still remain in google index.
I need solution to redirect the URLs which have trailing slash after php then have other file path to come back to original.

I need help to redirect eg:

```
mydomain.com/somefile.php/somefilesss.php?aaa=bbb&ddd=ddd
```

to

```
mydomain.com/somefile.php
```

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible explanations to this:

1. *Fantastic*: somethere in the web, this links exist and google follows them;
2. *Realistic*: there is a bug somethere in your php engine, which produces such links and google follows them.

So IMHO you should not care about creating a rewrite rule, but check php engine for this bug.

As time passes google will "forget" previously collected urls.

Comment: yep i know, i also create robot.txt to denied google crawl those links.. 
Have check php but my knowlege is limit ..
Hope some one can give me solution htaccess that send user corect urls when they search from some where else

Comment: @Binh This can be quite problematic to do if your scripts accept parameters. In this case some fully legit parameters may be stripped on redirect and it may display an error or completely different content. Without knowing all those aspects I would simply not recommend you to do this. Plus keep in mind that in this URL `mydomain.com/somefile.php/somefilesss.php?aaa=bbb&ddd=ddd` this part is actually query string `/somefilesss.php?aaa=bbb&ddd=ddd` and removing only part of parameters in such case can be problematic task... better check your code and check where such links came from.